# Is rationality a deformation invariant property for smooth threefolds?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $X\to S$ be a family of smooth projective complex threefolds over a connected base $S$, could it happen that for some $a, b\in S(\mathbb{C})$, the fiber $X_a$ is birational to $\mathbb{P}^3_{\mathbb{C}}$, while the fiber $X_b$ is not birational to $\mathbb{P}^3_{\mathbb{C}}$?

Comment: Did you mean $\mathbb{P}^3$?

Comment: @PiotrAchinger Yes, sorry for that..

Comment: By recent work of Kontsevich-Tschinkel (Invent. Math. 217 (2019)), rationality is preserved under specialization. So, if  your situation occurs, the generic fibre of your family must be *non-rational*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe this is still an open question in dimension $3$.

There is an example due to Hassett, Kresch and Tschinkel ([Stable rationality in smooth families of threefolds](https://arxiv.org/abs/1802.06107)) of a smooth projective family of threefolds over a connected base where some fibers are *stably* rational and others are not.

Also in dimension at least $4$, there are several examples of families over a connected base where $X_a$ is rational and $X_b$ is not even stably rational (you can find references in the linked paper).